# Formatting big.Rat using golang.org/x/text/message

Tags: go, formatting

The package [`golang.org/x/text/message`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/message) allows us to format numbers using national formats:

```golang
const n = 1222333.444555

prEn := message.NewPrinter(language.English)
prEn.Printf("%20.6f\n", n)
// Prints:
//     1,222,333.444555

prRu := message.NewPrinter(language.Russian)
prRu.Printf("%20.6f\n", n)
// Prints:
//     1 222 333,444555
```

Can I use it with `math/big.Rat`? That is, something like (doesn't work):

```
rat := big.NewRat(1222333444555, 1000000)
prEn.Printf("%20.6f\n", rat.FloatString(6))
// Should print:
//     1,222,333.444555
```

I know that I can wrap `Rat` in my own type and implement [`fmt.Formatter`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Formatter), but maybe there is a built-in way already?

Comment: Isn't obtaining its value as `float64` and formatting that sufficient? `x, _ := rat.Float64(); prEn.Printf("%20.6f\n", x)` yields your desired output.

Comment: In this particular case, yes. But when I need more precision or I need the precision to be guaranteed this won't cut it.

Comment: It looks this is currently not supported but "planned". See `text/internal/number/decimal.go` [currently line #308](https://github.com/golang/text/blob/master/internal/number/decimal.go#L308).

Comment: I see. Thanks for investigating. I'll see what can be done with that.